# Removing set from vector of sets

Tags: c++, vector, set

I have a vector full of sets, I am using this piece of code to look for an int in the vector:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= vector.size(); ++j){
  if(vector[j].find(find) != vector[j].end())
   std::cout << "FOUND: " << propagator << "\n";
  }
}
```

This will output when 'find' is found, is there anyway of returning the position of that set in the vector

For example if find = 5, and my vector contained the elements:

```
[0] 2 3 
[1] 4 5
```

Is there anyway I could return the set at position 1, eventually I want to remove the whole set from the array

I have been using

```
for(int j = 0; j <= vector.size(); ++j){
  if(vector[j].find(find) != vector[j].end())
    vector.erase (vector.begin()+j);
  }
```

Comment: You already have the position - `j`

Comment: I do not understand. You say you have a vector of sets and you search for an int in your vector.
Also, switch your `for` statement to `for(size_t j = 0; j <= vector.size(); ++j)` in order to void warnings.

Comment: Could you provide a usecase? Perhaps a different container would better suite your needs

Comment: @MrDuk It is for the unit clause algorithm,taking in a file of the CNF format. So there will be x clauses (in this example entries into the vector) and y variables within each element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not difficult to return the position. For example you could use standard algorithm `std::find_if` and then apply function `std::distance` to determine the position. Or you can write the function yourself using a loop

```
std::vector<std::set<int>>::size_type i = 0;

while ( i < v.size() && v[i].find( key ) == v[i].end() ) ++i;

if ( i != v.size() ) v.erase( std::next( v.begin(), i ) );
```

or

```
auto it = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(),
                        [&]( const std::set<int> &s )
                        [
                           return ( s.find(key ) != s.end() );
                        } );

if ( it != v.end() ) v.erase( it );
```

If you need to delete all elements of the vector that contain a given value (key) then you can use standard algorithm `std::remove_if` along with member function `erase`

Answer (score 0):

Use what you already have, no need to loop and search again:

```
vector.erase(vector.begin() + j);
```

Unless you're wanting to delete multiple sets at a time? That could get (*only slightly*) more complicated.

Comment: I will need to delete multiple sets yes, once the sets containing (find) have been deleted. (find) will be updated with a new int, which will then need to be deleted

Comment: you may have to be a little bit careful about erasing in the same loop as you are finding since `vector::erase` may invalidate iterators and indices.

Answer (score 0):

Additional note: you are going beyond the limit of your vector in this line:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= vector.size(); ++j){
```

You have to iterate while `j < vector.size()`. Although you can do it with an `int`, the type to do it fussily correct is `size_t` (that matches `vector<T>::size()`:

```
for(size_t j = 0; j < vector.size(); ++j){
```